# Forcing scroll bar outside flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to design my page with a thin banner in the center filled with content using flex to make it the height of the display minus the header.

But, when I make the content of the banner taller than the content, it puts the scrollbar inside the banner and not the content/page itself and this makes it very hard for the user to scroll.

Here's the code I've tried:

```css
body {
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
div.header {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
}
div.content {
    flex: auto;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
div.banner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">
        Header!
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="banner">
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I've tried mixing around the `overflow: auto;` and such, but nothing seems to be working.

Is there anyway to force the scroll bar to be outside the banner and inside the content?
I also don't want to use a fixed height for the header's height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the code snippets to see if this is your desired output.

```css
body {
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
div.header {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
}
div.content {
    flex: auto;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
div.banner {
    /*height: 100%;*/ /*Comment out height */
    width: 150px;
    overflow: visible; /* Change overflow to visible */
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">
        Header!
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="banner">
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `comment out`:

```
div.banner {
    ...
 /* overflow: auto; */
    ...
    margin: auto; /* Use for centering */
 /* position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%); */
}
```

```css
body {
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
div.header {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
}
div.content {
    flex: auto;
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
div.banner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
 /* overflow: auto; */
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: auto; /* Use for centering */
 /* position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%); */
    
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">
        Header!
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="banner">
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
            This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>This is very tall.<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```